How to configure content_security_policy on Nomad?
My task is to adjust content_security_policy for the Nomad. I'vt added the configuration to the Nomad according to the official guide.
My configuration:
ui {
  enabled = true

  content_security_policy {
    connect_src = ["'self'", "https://api.example.com", "https://another-api.example.com"]
    default_src = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "https://trusted-site.com"]
    form_action = ["'self'", "https://secure-form.example.com"]
    frame_ancestors = ["'none'"]
    img_src = ["'self'", "data:", "https://cdn.example.com"]
    script_src = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "https://scripts.example.com"]
    style_src = ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "https://styles.example.com"]
  }
}

My crossdomain.xml (nomad-client-host:4646/ui/crossdomain.xml)
<!-- 
 Copyright (c) HashiCorp, Inc.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: BUSL-1.1
 -->
<cross-domain-policy>
<!--  Read this: www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html  -->
<!--  Most restrictive policy:  -->
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="none"/>
<!--  Least restrictive policy:  -->
<!-- 
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
   -->
</cross-domain-policy>

Could you please tell me, where I made mistake?
Made as in the official guide.
